# Linux to Windows C++ port

Tags: c++, windows, linux, porting

I am trying to port my C++ application from Linux to Windows (Visual C++).
I am just curious wheter you know about any script/tool that would scan the source code and check for possible issues (such as dirent.h etc).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool like that. This kind of work is usually done by hand.

Comment: @karlphillip: Compilers usually do a great job of listing missing header files.  `make` might even list missing header files (if you've got the right dependency rules set up, e.g. by running `makedepend` or `gcc -MD`).

Comment: @Ben Thank you. But I assumed he was referring to a Windows tool.

Comment: @karlphillip: People make compilers for Windows too :)

Comment: @Ben lol Then answer the question and *make* @Petr very happy.

Answer (score 5):

The first tool is called your compiler.  It will tell you if your program compiles.

The second tool is called running whatever tests you may have.  They will tell you if the resulting binary works.

What were you looking for, a crystal ball to save you from doing work?  Regardless of what approach you take or what you may read to help you get started, you will at some point have to (1) compile the thing and (2) check to see that it works.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys  or  http://www.cygwin.com/

edit:
Cygwin is essentially a compatibility layer (implemented as a dll) between Unix/Posix and windows - the code should be unchanged, but there can be issues between different version of the cygwin dll.

Msys+Mingw is a subset of Unix/Posix libs reimplemented in win32 and a port of the gcc compiler plus essential build tools. The resulting exe runs completely natively but some complex build procedures need more work.

Either way if the app uses X then you also need an X-server, both of these provide one. But if you are doing lots of graphics and the app is written using something like Qt or wxWidgets you are going to have a reasonable amount of pain getting it to work.

Comment: Hi and thanks. What about performance are msys and cygwin comparable to the native Visual C++ under Windows?

Comment: @Petr: The only significant performance impact will be any code which uses `fork`, which is difficult to implement on Windows without Interix. The bigger issue with using cygwin is that any of your users are going to have to install cygwin before they'll be able to run the program.

Comment: Does msys contain some sort of POSIX emulation layer? Does it emulate `fork()`?

Comment: @ssmir, yes it's Posix implemented in win32. AFAIK it doesn't do fork() - The fork() concept doesn't really work on Windows where it's expensive to spawn processes

Comment: MSYS is NOT made to build applications for! Your explanation is flawed: MinGW provides native GCC with its own "Windows SDK" headers and import libraries. MSYS is *only* a development environment (ie a Bash shell to run `configure && make` from). MSYS also does not provide an X implementation. If you need POSIX on Windows, use Cygwin, if your project uses autotools, use MSYS+MinGW to build a native windows application, or better yet, adopt something more cross-platform than autotools, say CMake or Bjam etc. Please correct your description of MSYS because it is *not* correct at all.

Comment: @Martin Ok, your edit made it better. However it's not clear which app is easier to port, an X11, Qt or wxWidgets one.

Comment: @ssmir a Qt or wxWidgets app will port with no work (if it's written properly) an X app will be a lot of work and the X server on windows will never behave quite how you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has an entry on the MSDN about the 'best' ways to manage a port from *nix to Win32.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx

Comment: That page contains useful resources, but I really don't understand those two links to random pages of Boost without even a line of comment... `:S`

Comment: @Matteo: I assumed it was basically Microsoft saying 'Use Boost' :)

Comment: me too, but linking to the Regressions statistics (?!?) and not writing a single line of comment is not the best way to say that. `:)` (BTW, you got my +1)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would just compile using MinGW (at least at first), to eliminate any possible gcc to MSVS issues (not to waste time with compiler-related issues).

Second, just compile the code and watch all the include files that were not found. Go to the code that includes those headers, figure out if it is a dependency that exists in Windows (but was just not installed or set in include-paths). If not, use cross-platform libraries to replace the non-portable libraries. Typical cross-platform libraries would include: Boost, OpenGL, SDL, Qt, etc. (depending on how much your application is doing). If it is just a command-line "number-crunching" software, you will probably find all you need in Boost.